# MySQL tablespace exists error, no access to ssh or drop database privilege

Tags: mysql, tablespace

When I'm trying to create a table I get this error:

```
Tablespace for table '`database`.`table`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT
```

I found many solutions to this but every single one requires SSH access to server or drop database privilege which I don't have.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I was saying to DROP DATABASE first but then I saw "no privilege". You really need to access server or at least need to be able to DROP this table.

Comment: When I am trying to drop the table I get error Unknown table `table`

Comment: what about DROP TABLESPACE?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-tablespace.html

Comment: DROP TABLESPACE `table` throw this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''